# PL/SQL json_value function gives error for large JSON document

Tags: json, oracle, plsql

A service is attempts to extract a roleid from a JSON object, but gives

```
Error report:
ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested
ORA-06512: at line 1801
01460. 00000 -  "unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

The code is

```
set serveroutput on
declare
    input_data      VARCHAR2(32000);
    lv_role_id     VARCHAR2 (100);
begin
    input_data := '';
    input_data:=input_data||'{';
    input_data:=input_data||'  "roleid": "2945",';
    input_data:=input_data||'  "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'  "category": [';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "31",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": false';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "32",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": false';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "33",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": true';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "34",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": true';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "35",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": false';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "36",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": false';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "37",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": false';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "38",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": false';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "39",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": false';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "40",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": false';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "41",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": false';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "43",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": false';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "42",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": false';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "44",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": false';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "45",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": false';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "46",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": false';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "47",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": false';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "48",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": false';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "49",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": false';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "50",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": false';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "51",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": false';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "52",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": false';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "53",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": false';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "54",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": false';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "55",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": false';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "56",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": false';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "57",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": false';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "58",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": false';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "59",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": false';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "60",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": false';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "81",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": false';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "314",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": false';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "276",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": false';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "86",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": false';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "72",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": false';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "271",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": false';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "78",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": false';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "383",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": false';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "206",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": false';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "210",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": false';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "384",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": false';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "122",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": false';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "352",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": false';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "307",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": false';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "291",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": false';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "125",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": false';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "236",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": false';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "82",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": false';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "247",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": false';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "234",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": false';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "232",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": false';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "112",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": false';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "66",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": false';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "107",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": false';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "71",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": false';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "73",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": false';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "246",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": false';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "192",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": false';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "273",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": false';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "80",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": false';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "106",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": false';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "195",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": false';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "144",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": false';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "262",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": false';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "118",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": false';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "109",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": false';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "160",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": false';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "272",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": false';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "238",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": false';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "156",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": false';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "178",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": false';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "339",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": false';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    input_data:=input_data||'    {';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "277",';
    input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": false';
    input_data:=input_data||'    },';
    // input_data:=much more data
    input_data:=input_data||'  ]';
    input_data:=input_data||'}';

    SELECT JSON_VALUE (input_data, '$.roleid' returning number) INTO lv_role_id FROM DUAL;

end;
/
```

However, despite what others might think, the size of the document appears to have an effect.  If I run the following much smaller JSON parsing it parses the value.

```
set serveroutput on
declare
    input_data      VARCHAR2(32000);
    lv_role_id     VARCHAR2 (100);
begin
    input_data := '';
    input_data:=input_data||'{';
    input_data:=input_data||'  "roleid": "2945",';
    input_data:=input_data||'  "featureid": "3"';
    input_data:=input_data||'}';

    SELECT JSON_VALUE (input_data, '$.roleid' returning number) INTO lv_role_id FROM DUAL;

end;
/
```

I tried getting the actual JSON payload and running it through a lint validator and even the long one is compliant.  Inserting the JSON into CLOB in a table, then running SELECT JSON_VALUE on the column worked.  The AskTom guy says the problem is returning a large value, but I think it's having a problem taking a large value.

Comment: two things - the AskTOM guys deal with questions like this every day, so maybe take another look at their answer and also, why not just declare input_dat as a CLOB? no need to select into a table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems your db version has an issue. It's not mentioned so I'd recommend upgrading or looking for patches. I reduced your example to have a loop that adds to the doc instead for ease of testing.  This is in db **19.3** and shows the json input_data is 31k in length and prints the expected message.

```
$ sql klrice/klrice

SQLcl: Release 19.2 Production on Fri Oct 04 14:48:32 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Fri Oct 04 2019 14:48:34 -04:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.3.0.0.0

SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL>
SQL> declare
        input_data      VARCHAR2(32000);
        lv_role_id     VARCHAR2 (100);
    begin
        input_data := '';
        input_data:=input_data||'{';
        input_data:=input_data||'  "roleid": "2945",';
        input_data:=input_data||'  "featureid": "3",';
        input_data:=input_data||'  "category": [';

       for i in 1..410 loop
       input_data:=input_data||'    {';
       input_data:=input_data||'      "featureid": "3",';
       input_data:=input_data||'      "id": "'|| i ||'",';
       input_data:=input_data||'      "ischecked": false';
       input_data:=input_data||'    },';
       end loop;

       input_data:=input_data||'  ]';
       input_data:=input_data||'}';

       SELECT JSON_VALUE (input_data, '$.roleid' returning number) INTO lv_role_id FROM DUAL;
       dbms_output.put_line('JSON Size:'|| length(input_data));
       dbms_output.put_line('Role:'|| lv_role_id);

   end;
 /
JSON Size:31110
Role:2945


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: just tested in 12.2, 18, and 19, and it works A-OK. version 12.1 - FAILS. If i switch input_data to a CLOB, it works!

Comment: @thatjeffsmith I think you're correct. I did ```select * from v$version and got: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
"CORE 12.1.0.2.0 Production"
TNS for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production`

Comment: @Woodsman cool, so you have a hard fix (upgrade) or an easy fix (CLOB!)

Comment: Not being an Oracle DBA, I wouldn't know if upgrading from our version to the next is hard or worth it. :)